# Contact deletion in Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, contactbuilder, contact-deletion

I've successfully processed contact deletion in Parent business unit,
but I'm having trouble with *setting automation program for deleting contacts in **Child BU***.

As far as I know, the contact deletion is only available in Enterprise level(Parent BU).

> I wonder if I have to look for another way such as filtering with queries etc to process contact deletion in Child BU, or can I still use the same script I've used for the Parent BU?

Thank you for your help, in advance!

Comment: Hi. What type of account do you have? Is it a standard Enterprise 2.0 account? See this article on what types of account there are: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_tenant_types.htm&type=5

Comment: Just a question back, for clarity's sake - What is it you are trying to achieve? contact deletion is by nature systemwide. Do you want to delete contacts _for one BU only_  (not possible, at least that's not what a contact deletion does) or do you want to delete contacts systemwide, _with the automation running in child BU_ ? Given that you want systemwide deletion, then the deletion SSJS will have to be processed in Parent BU, but you can of course run all queries in a child BU, deposit data in a shared Data extension and pick that up with the Parent BU automation.

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak hi. We do have Enterprise2.0 account. Sorry for missing an important information!

Comment: @JonasLamberty To make it clear, I was wondering if I could process SSJS for contact deletion on Child BU without any additional configuration. As far as I know, contact deletion is only available on Enterprise Level Business Unit, so I thought I can't process the same script I wrote for the Parent BU contact deletion.  
Just to double-check if I understood your advice clearly, can I only delete data in a shared DE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

Contact deletion is by nature systemwide.

Given that you are aware of that and want systemwide deletion, then the deletion SSJS will have to be processed in Parent BU (Enterprise level).

This makes sense in so far as it will need to delete / anonymize also data that resides in entities on Enterprise level, think All Contacts, All Subscribers,...)

To be clear: It's just the SSJS deletion script that has to run in Parent BU context. One of many reasons why it's a good practice to have a Parent BU as an administrative layer.

How you make the data available for the process can be more multi-faceted. E.g. You can run queries that pull data from other data extensions in a child BU, deposit the resulting data in a Shared Data extension to make it available for parent context, and pick that up with the Parent BU deletion automation. A Shared Data Extension always has Parent BU context, but can be fed data from child BUs using SQL. That would be one easy way to use child BU automations to make data accessible to another automation running in Parent BU context.

"Local" Parent BU Data Extensions work just as well with a deletion script running in parent, but it's harder to get Child BU data into them.

Comment: Thanks for kind description:)